# Is $\sqrt{-1}$ equal to $i$ or $\pm i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

In complex numbers is $\sqrt{-1}$ equal to $i$ or $\pm i$ ?

In both cases how do we explain it?

The question arose when I saw it in Lathi's book (Linear Systems and Signals).

Comment: Doesn't matter. Although $i$ and $-i$ are additive(and multiplicative) inverses of each other, there is no *algebraic* difference. You can choose anyone to be $\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: I think the most *usual* definition is $\;\sqrt{-1}:=i\;$ , and this helps only to make things standard. Just like by definition $\;\sqrt4=2\;$ and *not* $\;\sqrt4=-2\;$ : no "natural" reason to choose one over the other, just simplicity and international (more or less..) standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$i^2=-1$ and $(-i)^2=-1$. In $\mathbb C$ these are the two distinct roots of equation $z^2+1=0$.

Based on that it might be tempting to say that $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and/or $\sqrt{-1}=-i$, but  we deal here with a function on $[0,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$ so $\sqrt{-1}$ is not defined properly here. Extension of the function to $\mathbb C$ leads to 'branches'.